# How to custome text of specific filed of a struct when call fmt.Printf("%+v", obj)

Tags: string, go, printing, tags

For example, there is a struct Student

```
type Student struct {
 Filed1 string
 Filed2 string
 Filed3 string
 Name *string
 Data []byte
}

func main(){
    name := "john"
    s := Student3{
        Filed1: "a",
        Filed2: "b",
        Filed3: "c",
        Name:   &name,
        Data:   []byte{1, 2, 3},
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", s)
}
```

The print result is:`{Filed1:a Filed2:b Filed3:c Name:0xc000167230 Data:[1 2 3]}%`

But I want custome the String() output of fields Name and Data

1. output of Name field be the origin value, not the pointer
2. output of Date field be the hex string, "0x010203", which is result of hex.EncodeToString(xxx)

So it's output will be `{Filed1:a Filed2:b Filed3:c Name:"john" Date:"0x010203"}`

Is there a simple way to implement it?

Comment: No, you cannot do this. You can implement the String method on Student, that's all you can do but you cannot tweak how %+v formats its output (especially you cannot change how primitive types are displayed). Just do not use %+v.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options. Like Volker wrote in his comment you can implement the String method on the struct. You can also use json.Marshal/MarshalIndent if you want it json formatted. That also gives you the option to name the fields differently in your output.

Here's an example of it:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Student struct {
    Field1 string `json:"fieldNameInJSON"`
    Field2 string
    Field3 string
    Name   *string
    Data   []byte
}

func (s Student) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("{ Field1: %s, Field2: %s, Field3: %s, Name: %s, Data: %v}", s.Field1, s.Field2, s.Field3, *s.Name, s.Data)
}

func main() {
    name := "john"
    s := Student{
        Field1: "a",
        Field2: "b",
        Field3: "c",
        Name:   &name,
        Data:   []byte{1, 2, 3},
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", s)
    fmt.Println(s)
    j, e := json.Marshal(s)
    if e == nil {
        fmt.Println(string(j))
    }
    j, e = json.MarshalIndent(s, " ", " ")
    if e == nil {
        fmt.Println(string(j))
    }
}
```

If you run in on [play](https://play.golang.org/p/hZhpgeP2i4K) you get the output:

```
{ Field1: a, Field2: b, Field3: c, Name: john, Data: [1 2 3]}
{ Field1: a, Field2: b, Field3: c, Name: john, Data: [1 2 3]}
{"fieldNameInJSON":"a","Field2":"b","Field3":"c","Name":"john","Data":"AQID"}
{
  "fieldNameInJSON": "a",
  "Field2": "b",
  "Field3": "c",
  "Name": "john",
  "Data": "AQID"
 }
```

***Edit:**

I missed you wanted to run hex.EncodeToString on the data field, you can of course add that in the String() method. If you want to do it for json you'll have to implement a Marshaler like described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31848836/json-marshal-struct-with-method-return-as-field)